# SQL syntax for ms-access query to pivot column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to organize data from previous sales for my company right now it looks like this:

```
Item1    Item2
Clock    Spring
Hands    Nuts
Dial     Clock
Clock    Hands
Hands    Spring
```

what I need is this

```
Item1   Product1   Product2
Clock   Spring    Hands
Hands   Nuts      Spring
Dial    Clock
```

I have about 1000 data points so I would like something dynamic but I got this far:

```
SELECT transdata.item1, Product1, Product2, Product3
(
SELECT transdata.item1, transdata.item2,
     'Product' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By transdata.[item1] Order By transdata.item1) AS Varchar(10)) AS ColSequence
FROM transdata
) Temp

PIVOT
(
MAX(Product)
For ColSequence in (Product1, Product2, Product3)
)PIV
```

It says I have a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

This can be really painful in MS Access.  But this relatively simple version works for at most two columns:

```
select item1, min(item2) as product1,
       iif(min(item2) <> max(item2), max(item2), null) as product2
from transdata
group by item1
```

Comment: is there a way to expand this to product'n' the problem is i have a ton of data not sure how many products maximum there are associated with item 1 values if not that is okay this will suffice for my work :) thank you again!

Comment: @StephStoudenmire . . . It is only possible to answer the question that is actually asked (well, in most cases at least).  This answers the question that you asked -- which is for two products in the pivot.  If you have a *different* question, then please ask it as a *new* question.